# Bad math delimiter in Scientific WorkPlace

Tags: errors, compiling

I have a .tex file that I created in Texshop, but I need to open and compile it into pdf in Scientific Workplace.  It can compile no problem in Texshop, but I receive the Bad math delimiter error when I compile it in SWP.  After the error it shows /{equation*}, even though I do not have that in the file.  Is someone familiar with what this issue could be?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The force is with us, but even then, we can not guess what you typed into that editor. Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: scientific workplace redefines quite a  lot of commands.  i think that includes adding `\left` and `\right` to some delimiters.  you may be running into one of the "variants", but to be sure, we need specific details.

Comment: Be also forewarned that S.W. does not support extended-tex (aka e-tex).  So that, too, will limit your available packages that you can use.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes: S.W doesn't support e-tex? Stone Age Workplace rather ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I've tried to assist a colleague using S.W.  The etex error was what I received.  I looked into it, and the best I could ascertain is that there were no newer versions than what he already had.  I get the impression that S.W. development ceased some time ago, and the company exists off of support and maintenance.  I could be wrong.